# Is a variable after initialization a reference?

Tags: c++

In this example, what is `x`? Is it a reference?

```
int x  = 5;   //What is x?
int &y = x;   //This is an alias for x
int *z = &x;  //This is a pointer to x
```

Comment: @specializt look at the given answer below

Comment: x, y, and z are all variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused.

x is an int variable. It is a concrete object of type int.

y is a reference. It is basically a pointer that's already deferenced for you. You can treat it as if it was x.

z is a pointer to x. It holds the memory address of x, so you can access it if needed. It needs to be deferenced.

Answer (score 5):

No *x* is `int` variable. *y* is reference to `int` (x)  and *z* is pointer to `int` (x).

Comment: Well that was easier than expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand the "non-reference variable" as something from which a reference can be taken. Every variable "consists of" a "reference", which is a language interface for it, and the internal representation, which is a piece of memory that holds its value.

If you create a "reference variable" and initialize it with some normal variable, you will create a new "reference", that is, another "language interface" (a separate name) that is pinned into the same internal representation as the source variable. Note that it's bound to the **internal representation** of the variable, not the variable itself.

The pointer simpy points to the representation itself. The pointed type is a potential type of the "reference" (that is, the language interface to the variable), if you do "pointer dereference" (use *z expression).

The actual type of an expression of the variable 'x' is 'int&'. If you pass it to a function or assign to another variable (in C++ they are both understood as "function call"), there will be a conversion from int& to int. Note, however, that if you pass it to a function where a template-parametrized type is used on that position, and it will be specified as "T x" (not "T& x"), then T will be picked up as 'int' (not int&), no matter if you passed an immediate int value or a variable of type int.

Comment: Expression cannot have the type `int&`

Comment: Expression does have type    int&   , for example here:

    int& GetLocation();
    ...
    SaveValue( GetLocation() ); --

The expression that forms the argument for SaveValue is of int& type.

Answer (score -2):

X is an integer variable.
int  &y =x; // is treated by compiler as int *const y = &x 
So reference operator is used as name aliasing for variables and reduces the complexity of dereferencing the value by developer.